# Cloud Run HTTP2 breaks CORS

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am running a basic Quarkus application on Google Cloud Run.

The default settings use HTTP 1.1 between Cloud Run and the backend container. If I [enable http2](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2) then CORS fails because the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is mangled and returns the origin and the wildcard together and so is rejected by the browser.

For example when testing my app using the online Swagger UI the response is: `access-control-allow-origin: https://petstore.swagger.io,*`

Testing my app locally with curl and h2c does not show the problem. Therefore it seems that Google Cloud Run is doing some mangling of this header.

Is there some config I can set to stop this from happening?

Comment: Have you tried not using http2? Does CORS work with the same application?

Comment: And can you share sample codes and setup? It looks like it uses custom domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to track down the underlying problem in the framework that I was using.

The bug was that the framework was returning duplicate headers. For example:

```
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-origin: https://petstore.swagger.io
```

There appears to be some weird behaviour in that cloud run had merged these into one header and then had concatenated the values.